# With any Git command getting log4cplus error message

Tags: git, git-bash

For each git command Ex. git pull, git push, git status

I am getting following message, which is very annoying

```
log4cplus:ERROR file is not open: C:\Users\<myUserName>\AppData\Local\Secure Islands\IQProtector\Logs\lsp.silog
```

Can you please help me get rid of it ?

Comment: umm... reinstall?

Comment: Tried that, didn't work :(
Not sure if it's something related to access over filesystem

Comment: Is it only occurs when you run Git commands? Maybe there is something wrong with, for example, related to $PS1 variable on your MinGW for running Git.

Comment: How do i confirm it or rather rectify it ?

Answer (score -1):

Try setting environment variable LOG4CPLUS_LOGLOG_QUIETMODE=1. This should disable all diagnostics output from log4cplus itself.

found here: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/autocad-forum/log4cplus-error/m-p/5879510/highlight/true#M101172

Comment: It's found where?